# C# - Retrieving data from mysql then storing into variables

Tags: c#, mysql

I have been trying a more efficient way to get and set data from my database in mysql to a variable. I've used a for loop to shorten the code and make it easier to read, though i can't think of a way to properly set other variables. Here's my code:

Note: I use 18 different local variables. (i.g ad, mnd, psk, pck, etc..)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
  MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price from products where productID = '" + i + "'";
  MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read()) {
    ad = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ToString());
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the prices of 18 products from the database, but on this piece of code, I can only set one price. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation. Use Parameters.

Comment: kind of new to c# so i'm familiarizing with the basics

Comment: Do you want specific Products or just a specific amount of results?

Comment: Maybe `where productID > 1 AND productID < 19` then you only have to run ONE query to get 18 result rows

Comment: ... or `SELECT TOP 18 ... ` or `... LIMIT 18` ...

Comment: User Dapper https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper, never use string concatenation like this, its often subject to SQL Injection Attacks and does  not make it easy for your server to optimise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @fildor specific products and then assigning them to their corresponding variables

Comment: That means you'll **always** have exactly these 18 products ... not less not more. Why use a DB then? Hardcode them.

Comment: Using `i = 1 to 18` is not slecting specific products, its selecting the first 18 products entered into the database

Comment: i thought of hardcoding but i might get shot at in school since we need to use a database

Comment: You can make changes both to your query and your design. If you have a list of product ids, you can combine them in your query using IN (select * from table where id in (id1, id2, ...). 
This will return a rowset and this you can map to a collection

Answer (score 1):

You assign all prices to 1 variable. Your code run like this

```
ad = 150; //sample price
ad = 240; 
ad = 100;
...(18 times)
```

You have to use array instead of single variable.

Change your code to :

```
  MySqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT price from products where productID > 1 AND productID < 19" ;
  MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  int counter = 0;
  while (reader.Read()) {
    ad[counter++] = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: naww. i use 18 vars, (ig ad, ig, mnd, etc..)

Comment: "naww. i use 18 vars, (ig ad, ig, mnd, etc..)" - That's bad design :/

Comment: what do you suggest sir @fildor?

Comment: because these variables will be used for calculating prices, so i thought 18 vars

Comment: We use arrays for this. You can simply reach any value with its index. for ex. ad[0], ad[1] etc.

Comment: No offense, Ivan - do you do this for a living or is this a spare-time project?

Comment: School activity, sir

Comment: There is a simple solution, if you must have 18 differently named variables. At the end of the suggested loop, you have 18 separate lines of code. *shudder*

`ad = ad[0];
mnd = ad[1];
...
psk = ad[17];`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, change your schema a bit, so you have

```
name    | price    | id
------------------------
'ad'      1.00       1
'mnd'     42.24      2
'psk'     6.66       3
'pck'     2.00       4
'etc'     9999.99    5
...
```

Then use Dapper like this,

```
using Dapper;

...

IDictionary<string, decimal> products; 
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
{
    connection.Open();
    products = connection.Query("SELECT name, price FROM products;")
        .ToDictionary(
            row => (string)row.Name,
            row => (decimal)row.Price);
}
```

then you can get whatever product you want like this,

```
var adPrice = products["ad"];
```

---

Once you have many products (a lot more than 18) you won't want to hold them all in memory at once but for now this would work well.